# Dart: Return variable without running function

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an array of items that looks like this:

```
  final List<Map<String, String>> dateIdeas = [
    {'Description': 'Drink Cocktails','Image': 'assets/images/cocktailsfull.jpg'},
    {'Description': 'Go for dinner!', 'Image': "assets/images/dinner.jpg"},
];
```

When the user taps a button the first item is removed from the array.

```
removeItem() {
    setState(() {
      dateIdeas.removeAt(index);
    });
  }
```

This works correctly. However, I want the user to be able to undo this action. My solution to this was to perform the following:

1. Have the `removeItem` function return what the array looked like before the removal:

```
  Map<String, String> removeItemLiked() {
    final removed = dateIdeas[index];
    setState(() {
      _controller.reset();
      likes.add(dateIdeas[index]['Description']);
      dateIdeas.removeAt(index);
    });
    return removed;
  }
```

2. Have an `undo` function that adds the item back into the array at index 0:

```
  void undo() {
    setState(() {
      Map<String, String> result = removeItemLiked();
      dateIdeas.insert(0, result);
    });
  }
```

The issue here is that when triggering the `undo` function it also retriggers `removeItem`. How can I have the old array stored to a variable so I can always use it later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `removeItem` is getting called by you within the `undo` function.
To prevent this, separate the function call from the `removed` variable.

```
// within stateful widget, declare 'removed'...
Map<String, String> removed;
```

Your other functions get modified like so;

```
  void removeItemLiked() {
    removed = dateIdeas[index];
    setState(() {
      _controller.reset();
      likes.add(dateIdeas[index]['Description']);
      dateIdeas.removeAt(index);
    });
 }

  void undo() {
    if(removed != null) {
        setState(() {
          dateIdeas.insert(0, removed);
        });
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the removed item in a variable like `lastRemoved` and store it's index and value both. Here's a simple example:

```dart
class MyNums {
  List<int> numbers = [123, 34, 5, 436, 56, 677];
  Map<String, dynamic> lastRemoved;

  removeItem(int index) {
    lastRemoved = {
      'index': index,
      'item': numbers[index],
    };
    numbers.removeAt(index);
  }

  undoRemove() {
    if (lastRemoved != null) {
      numbers.insert(lastRemoved['index'], lastRemoved['item']);
    }
    lastRemoved = null;
  }
}
```

Test:

```dart
main() {
  MyNums nums = MyNums();
  print('initial:\t\t ${nums.numbers}');

  nums.removeItem(2);
  print('remove from index 2:\t ${nums.numbers}');

  nums.undoRemove();
  print('undo index 2:\t\t ${nums.numbers}');

  nums.removeItem(2);
  print('remove from index 2:\t ${nums.numbers}');

  nums.removeItem(2);
  print('remove from index 2:\t ${nums.numbers}');

  nums.undoRemove();
  print('undo index 2:\t\t ${nums.numbers}');

  nums.undoRemove();
  print('nothing to undo:\t ${nums.numbers}');
}
```

Output:

```
initial:                 [123, 34, 5, 436, 56, 677]
remove from index 2:     [123, 34, 436, 56, 677]
undo index 2:            [123, 34, 5, 436, 56, 677]
remove from index 2:     [123, 34, 436, 56, 677]
remove from index 2:     [123, 34, 56, 677]
undo index 2:            [123, 34, 436, 56, 677]
nothing to undo:         [123, 34, 436, 56, 677]
```